# weird text place on the top of the column with makecell in latex table

Tags: tables, makecell

I want that the text is placed in the top of the column in my table. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell} % sauter une ligne dans un tableau


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{m{2cm} m{13cm}} 
        Authors:& my name \\
        Date:& \today \\
        Lecture:& Essentials of advanced astrophysics \\
        Lecturer:&  my prof \\ \hline \hline
        \makecell[l]{Declaration: \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ } & I hereby declare that this thesis is my own work and that I have not used any sources and aids other than those stated in the thesis. I [AGREE/DO NOT AGREE] with making this document available to other students of the course on a password protected website. [PLACE], [DATE][NAME][SIGNATURE] 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

but it shows me this:

[image]

As you can see, Declaration and I hereby are not on the same line... Does anyone knows why and how I can fix it ?

Comment: Use `p`instead of `m` type columns and drop the `\makecell` command around the "Declaration" part. Personally, I would also use an `l` type column for the first column, probably in combination with `tabularx` in order to make sure the table is exactly as wide as the textwidth.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you <3

Comment: Do you mean using l in \makecell ? And tabularx instead of tabular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` type columns will result in vertically centered text. Since you seem to want to top align the text in your table, use `p` type columns and drop the `\makecell` command.

In the following MWE, I have also included a second version of your table, using the `tabularx` package. With this package, you can automatically adjust the width of a table to the textwidth (or another width of your choice).

In the following screenshot, the red lines indicate the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell} % sauter une ligne dans un tableau

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[H]
%   \centering
\noindent
   \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{13cm}} 
        Authors:& my name \\
        Date:& \today \\
        Lecture:& Essentials of advanced astrophysics \\
        Lecturer:&  my prof \\ \hline \hline
        Declaration: & I hereby declare that this thesis is my own work and that I have not used any sources and aids other than those stated in the thesis. I [AGREE/DO NOT AGREE] with making this document available to other students of the course on a password protected website. [PLACE], [DATE][NAME][SIGNATURE] 
    \end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}} 
        Authors:& my name \\
        Date:& \today \\
        Lecture:& Essentials of advanced astrophysics \\
        Lecturer:&  my prof \\ \hline \hline
        Declaration: & I hereby declare that this thesis is my own work and that I have not used any sources and aids other than those stated in the thesis. I [AGREE/DO NOT AGREE] with making this document available to other students of the course on a password protected website. [PLACE], [DATE][NAME][SIGNATURE] 
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the very clear answer ! It helps a lot !